# How to create Bitbucket repositories from CLI on the hosting server

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm looking for some help on how to create a large number (70 total) of Bitbucket repos on the host server using the curl command and the Bitbucket API. I have reviewed a number of links in my research, but all I get are HTTP 404 errors using the syntax found on those websites.

This is the latest command string I have recently found, but haven't tested yet. Does this appear to be what I need to make this process work?

curl -X POST -u $USER:$(cat $HOME/.pw) -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://bitbucket..com/2.0/repositories/ -d '{"is_private": true, "scm": "git", "project": {"key": "ABC"}}'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to create multiple repos, but that was in cloud version of Bitbucket. I came up with a python script to handle it.

1. I had a property file where the repository name will be the section name.

```
[test-repository6]
project_key=CUS
project_description=This is test-repository6
private_repository=true
```

2. Using config parser, I read data from the property file

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('repository.properties')
```

3. A JSON file which contains the data to create the repository

```
"{\"scm\": \"git\", \"is_private\": \"{private_repository}\", \"fork_policy\": \"no_public_forks\", \"project\": {\"key\": \"{project_key}\"}, \"description\": \"{project_description}\"}"
```

4. Finally the python script to create the repositories mentioned in the property file

```
from subprocess import call
import configparser
import subprocess
import shutil
import json

project_key = config.get(section_name, "project_key")
project_description = config.get(section_name, "project_description")
private_repository = config.get(section_name, "private_repository")

if(private_repository == "true"):
   cmd = 'curl --url "' + bb_url +"/"+ section_name + '" --user ' + bb_user + ':' + bb_pwd + ' --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data ' + open(os.path.join(base_dir, "repo_creation_private.json"), "r").readline().replace("{project_key}", project_key).replace("{project_description}", project_description).replace("{private_repository}", private_repository)
else:
  cmd = 'curl --url "' + bb_url +"/"+ section_name + '" --user ' + bb_user + ':' + bb_pwd + ' --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data ' + open(os.path.join(base_dir, "repo_creation_public.json"), "r").readline().replace("{project_key}", project_key).replace("{project_description}", project_description).replace("{private_repository}", private_repository)
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).communicate()
```

You can put this under a loop to iterate through all the sections in the property file.

Comment: Interesting you mention the target differences between the Cloud and server versions of Bitbucket. It is possible that Atlassian would not implement the API to work the same for the targets?

Comment: API functionality are the same. The difference will be in the URL of the API request for cloud and on-prem versions.

Comment: I created a json file

Comment: $ cat load.json
{
\"name\": \"devdocs\",
\"scm\": \"git\",
\"is_private\": \"true\",
\"fork_policy\": \"no_public_forks\",
\"description\": \"test\"
}

Comment: The command I executed
$ curl -v POST -u user:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.bitbucket.org/rest/1.0/project/" -d load.json

Comment: Ends with a HTTP/400 message that is telling me I'm missing or using some parameters incorrectly. Ends with "bad request". How do I correct this?

Comment: I believe these escape characters `\\` are only needed when you go with python. Try removing all the special characters since you are using curl!

Comment: I also posted to Atlassian and found the answer. This URL point to the solution for my purposes. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/HTTP-1-1-404-when-using-the-POST-method-creating-new-Bitbucket/qaq-p/1677468#U1678288